# Usage of Domain from one server to another

Tags: server, dns-domain

Just want to ask if anyone have an idea about how to do this.

I'm using a domain lets call it mymaindomain.com to connect to my Main Server, now I have a second Server that uses mysecondomain.com

Is there a way to create a subdomain that goes to mysecondomain.com/folderneedtoview?

Thanks alot

Comment: Please read the [help]. This question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to make a redirect on the sub-domain, so here is what i suggest.

Make a Sub-domain.
And in the Sub domain Make a redirect to "mysecondomain.com/folderneedtoview"

Simple as that.